# Error de python con condicionales elif no tomado en cuenta

Tags: python

El error es que cuando ejecuto mi código con la condicional if lo ejecuta bien pero cuando pruebo el elif no lo toma en cuenta y va directo al if por alguna razón. Aquí el código:

```
nombre_usuario=str(input("como debo de llamarte usuario?... "))

verificacion=str(input("excelente, vuestro nombre es "+str(nombre_usuario)+" 

correcto??? responde de manera afirmativa para si, negativa para no "))

if verificacion=="si "or"SI"or"Si"or"S"or"s":

    print("afirmativo verificacion confirmada "+str(nombre_usuario))

elif verificacion=="no"or"NO"or"No"or"N"or"n":

    print("afirmativo nombre no valido...reiniciando protocolo_inicio")
```

Comment: Si te ha servido mi respuesta aceptamela por favor, un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Otra alternativa donde lo haces más simple y no tienes que poner tantos '**or**' en la sentencia **if** sería utilizando una **lista** (*list*) con los diferentes repuestas que puede dar el usuario:

```
nombre_usuario = str(input("como debo de llamarte usuario?... "))

verificacion = str(input("excelente, vuestro nombre es "+str(nombre_usuario)+"correcto??? responde de manera afirmativa para si, negativa para no "))

palabras_no = ['no', 'No', 'n', 'NO', 'oN']
palabras_si = ['si', 'SI', 'Si', 'S', 'sI']

if verificacion in palabras_no:
    print('Hago lo que sea no.')

if verificacion in palabras_si:
    print('Hago lo que sea si.')
```

Y para no tener que tener tantas opciones puedes siempre pasar lo que el 'usuario' escribe a minúsculas con la función **lower()** que es una práctica que se suele realizar.

nombre_usuario = str(input("como debo de llamarte usuario?... "))

```
verificacion = str(input("excelente, vuestro nombre es "+str(nombre_usuario)+"correcto??? responde de manera afirmativa para si, negativa para no "))

palabras_no = ['no', 'n']
palabras_si = ['si', 's']

if verificacion.lower() in palabras_no:
    print('Hago lo que sea no.')

if verificacion.lower() in palabras_si:
    print('Hago lo que sea si.')
```